# CSS3 media query error

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to change a webpage design **if device screen width is greater than 1024px** for this I using `@media only screen and (min-width: > 1024px){ }` **but it is not working** .

Please tell me what is the solution .

Comment: try @media screen and (min-width:1024px) ?

Comment: I want to change a webpage design if device screen width is greater than 1024px . For this what is the solution ?

Comment: for  greater than 1024px what ?

Comment: you have a spelling error in 'media' and you should omit the greater than '>' sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current code that you have tried to implement *will* do the trick, but only if you rectify the syntax errors in it.

So, instead of

`@media only screen and (min-width: > 1024px){ }`

you could do

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px){ 
    /* css rules here will apply only if the size of the screen is greater than AND equal to 1024px */
}
```

**Note:** *@media query values specified for the `min-width`|`max-width` will be inclusive of the value itself as well. Meaning that if you want that a particular style apply to an element* **exactly** *when the width of the screen is greater than 1024px (and not equal to it), you should change the value to `min-width: 1025px`.*

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/97tr2ksh/)

```
@meida only screen and (min-width: > 1024px){...}
```

use this

```
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {...}
/* styles for browsers larger than 1024px; */ 

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {...}   
/* styles for browsers less than 1024px; */
```

}